# How to email a pdf from IIS site using local Outlook

Tags: javascript, email, pdf, outlook, iis-6

I built several pdf documents with built in javascript to email the document from an outlook account. These documents are on the company's intranet where the idea was to be able to quickly access them and send them to the customer. When the email button on the PDF document was click it brought up an outlook window that said undefined in all fields and did not show the pdf attached. When closing the outlook window a message popped up saying "Failed to Update Headers." I've been trying to find a solution to this and everything I haven't found anything on this. Any help on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.